# PHP/MySQL How to show a database row from a new window?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has so many columns that I have to create a link to view more of it.

Example of how I print my current database.

> row 1 | c1 | c2 | c3 | ... | c(n-m) | 'View More'
>
> row 2 | c1 | c2 | c3 | ... | c(n-m) | 'View More'

And here's my code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){   //creates a loop to loop through results

echo "<tr><td>";    //start a row and cell tag in HTML

for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){ //Creates a loop to print the results

    if($i == 1){    //concatenates the names
        echo $row[$search_value[$i + 1]] . " " . $row[$search_value[$i + 2]] . " " . $row[$search_value[$i]] . "</td><td>";
        $i = $i + 2; //skips the next two since its already printed
    } else if($i == 5){ //concatenates the addresses
        echo $row[$search_value[$i]] . ", " . $row[$search_value[$i + 1]] . ", " . $row[$search_value[$i + 2]] . "</td><td>";
        $i = $i + 2; //skips the next two since its already printed
    } else {
        echo $row[$search_value[$i]] . "</td><td>"; //prints the specified value and the end and start of a table cell
    }
}

echo "<a href='view_more.php' target='_blank'>View More</a>";
echo "</tr></td>";  //ends a row and cell tag in HTML

}
```

Now how do I actually print out the rest of the data of the specific row? (When I click on the 'View More' of row 1, how do I show the rest of the data from row 1?)

I was planning on passing that one unique value with the link and just searching for that again in that new page and just printing it. But again, "how do i do that?".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that value in $_GET:

```
 $pk = $row['primary_key'];
 echo "<a href='view_more.php?row_id=$pk' target='_blank'>View More</a>";
```

and then in view_more.php you use that row_id in the where cluase

```
 SLECT .... WHERE primary_key=$_GET['row_id'].
```

But if you're going to use ajax you have to move this to a post or [get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) funciton.
and use the same technique by passing the id of the row (or the [index](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) of that row).